# tkinter: How to use locals() function in tkinter class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use `locals()` in `root.keyboard()` so that I could get a dictionary of all the variables in `root.keyboard()`

The code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(root, self).__init__()

        self.minsize(820,700)
        self.configure(bg='black')
        self.keyboard()

    def keyboard(self):
        self.key_Q=Label(self, text="Q", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=40,y=450)
        self.key_W=Label(self, text="W", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=115,y=450)
        self.key_E=Label(self, text="E", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=190,y=450)
        self.key_R=Label(self, text="R", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=265,y=450)
        self.key_T=Label(self, text="T", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=340,y=450)
        self.key_Y=Label(self, text="Y", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=415,y=450)
        self.key_U=Label(self, text="U", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=490,y=450)
        self.key_I=Label(self, text="I", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=565,y=450)
        self.key_O=Label(self, text="O", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=640,y=450)
        self.key_P=Label(self, text="P", font="Calibri 15", height=2, width=6, fg='white', bg="#3A3A3C").place(x=715,y=450)

root = root()
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that if I put `print(locals())` in `root.keyboard()`, I am not getting any of the variables in it. That's what I'm getting:
`{'self': <__main__.root object .>}`

Comment: Instance attributes are an entirely different thing than local variables.  You could find `key_Q` and similar in `self.__dict__` - but they're going to be mixed in with various other attributes.  It might be better to create an explicit dict holding only the keys - `self.keys['Q'] = Label(...` perhaps.  (Note that these values are all None currently - the result of calling `.place()`, rather than the actual Label.)

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @jasonharper in the comments:

Instance attributes are an entirely different thing than local variables. You could find `key_Q` and similar in `self.__dict__` - but they're going to be mixed in with various other attributes. It might be better to create an explicit dict holding only the keys - `self.keys['Q'] = Label(...` perhaps. (Note that these values are all None currently - the result of calling `.place()`, rather than the actual Label.)